How to skip/not_probe certain hardware features (firmware)?
I would like to harder/clean my system and a have read about clearcpuid and initcall_blacklist.
How can i skip some hardware-machine, built-in linux and modules, certain code_snippet (firmwares) from working on.
Remove /lib/firmware/specific_firmware.bin is quite easy, but it is not elegant and provoke errors/fails log.
Does we have a way to neutralize/block fetch_firmware auto_started (from post), from linux and from kernel_object (ko).
Maybe spoofing a valid nvram or imitating a valid should works
I am not talking to a virtualized system. Linux native in place.
Thx
Luiz

One way of handling it is to re-compile the kernel with the features turned off.
You can download the kernel source from kernel.org, and install the build dependencies.
apt-get install git fakeroot build-essential ncurses-dev xz-utils libssl-dev bc flex libelf-dev bison

Then use "make menuconfig"
You will get a DOS like GUI where you can choose what to enable and what to disable.
Save and exit the GUI when you are satisfied with your choices.
make -j 4
make -j 4 modules_install
make install 
update-grub

Reboot and make sure everything is working.  You should be able to choose the previous kernel version in grub if something goes wrong.
Additional "make localmodconfig" could be used instead or in addition to "make menuconfig".  This option will remove any module not actively being used by the kernel.  You will go from about 3000 modules to about 200 modules, but you will lose support for anything not actively in use.
In most cases you will have to go back afterwards, and reactivate (rebuild the kernel) some modules.  Especially for USB devices that were unplugged at the time you did this.
